# C++ enums and inline header functions

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, compiler-errors

When using an `enum` in C++ how does one create getter and setters?

Example:

```
enum class FieldLayerStates
{
        kEmpty = 0, // new to the game.
        kActive = 1, // has fields already in the same.
        kAdd = 2 // field layer is ready to have a field added.
};

FieldLayerStates _fieldLayerState;

inline FieldLayerStates getFieldLayerState() { return _fieldLayerState; };

inline void setFieldLayerState(FieldLayerStates i) { _fieldLayerState = i; };
```

I am getting errors at the inline functions:

```
: Unknown type name 'FieldLayerStates'
: Cannot initialize return object of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'FieldLayer::FieldLayerStates'
```

and when I go to use it:

```
 // check the status of the layer to see if it has fields in it already (loaded from CCUserDefaults
if (getFields().empty())
{
    // nothing, this must be our first time in.
    setFieldLayerStatus(kEmpty);
}
```

It says `kEmpty` is undeclared.

Can someone help me clear up my confusion?

Comment: From the comments I guess that you want to use a bit field to store different states, enums are not good for that. You stated your problem completely wrong, that's why you don't get what people are saying to you! I recommend a simple class with public properties which then may have getters/setters, the class will act as a bit field they way you want it, lose the enums.

Comment: @Paul, enums are fine for bitmasks, _scoped_ enums aren't convenient for that though

Comment: @JonathanWakely How are enums good for storing state? It's not like you can do: UserState::IsOnline = 1; or UserState::IsOnline = 0; if UserState is an enum.

Comment: @Paul, UserState state = IsOnline; if(state == IsOnline) ... What's wrong with that? The C++ standard even says an enum can be used to implement bitmasks, see clause 17. Maybe you are missing the difference between an enumeration type and an enumerator?

Comment: Oh man, I screwed up, I'm sorry for the confusion I made. @JonathanWakely Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enum class Foo
```

is a new C++11 language feature that means "strongly typed, and scoped" enumerations. It is significantly different than just

```
enum Foo
```

When you use strongly typed enums, you have to qualify them with the scope they are contained in.

```
enum class Colors { Red, Green, Blue };
enum class Moods  { Happy, Bored, Blue };
```

Without the "class", this won't compile, because you have defined "Blue" twice. With the "Class" you have actually defined two scopes with their own, private, scoped enums, that require the "::" operator to access.

The "class" are also strongly typed, which means that they won't cast - e.g. to an integer type - without you explicitly casting them.

```
enum COLORS { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
enum class Colors { Red, Green Blue };

int i = RED; // Legal
Colors j = Colors::Red; // Legal
int i = Colors::Red; // Illegal: Colors::Red is not an integer, it's a Colors.
Colors j = Red; // Illegal: You didn't specify the scope.
Colors j = RED; // Illegal: RED is an integer, not a Colors.

for (int i = RED; i <= BLUE; ++i) { cout << i << endl; } // Legal
// But Colors is not a numeric type, you can't do math or increment on it,
// so the following is illegal:
for (auto j = Colors::Red; j <= Colors::Blue; ++j)

enum class Flags = { Herp = 1, Derp = 2 };
Flags combo = Flags::Herp;
combo |= Flags::Derp; // Illegal, no '|' operator for Flags, casting required.
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using an `enum class`, are you sure that's what you want?

If you stop doing that your code will work.

otherwise refer to `FieldLayerStates::kEmpty` (because enumerators of an `enum class` must be qualified by their type name)

I don't know why you get the `Unknown type name 'FieldLayerStates'` error because you haven't shown enough context to understand the code, at a guess I'd say you're trying to define the functions outside the class and you need to say `FieldLayer::FieldLayerStates`

Please show the **full** code so we have a chance of seeing what you're really compiling.

Comment: removing `class` still results in the unknown type errors. Am I using Enum wrong in this case?

Comment: Hard to know since you haven't shown the actual code you're compiling.

Comment: Sorry Paul, a clean and re-build took care of it. I did post everything except from my .cpp where I was setting the variable. Everything works now. I went and looked up `enum class` and I see my mistake now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want this

```
enum FieldLayerStates
{
    kEmpty = 0, // new to the game.
    kActive = 1, // has fields already in the same.
    kAdd = 2 // field layer is ready to have a field added.
};
```

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't compile or wasn't valid, but based on how is he using it, I believe this is what he wants.

Comment: @Jason, it's called C++11, and `enum class` is valid but you're using it wrong, and if you just say `enum` you wouldn't get the `kEmpty is undeclared` error